# getElementsByTagName returning undefined

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have a function with one parameter which is an ID string:

```
function experimentOne(masterContainer) {
```

Which I call with:

```
experimentOne('#experimentOne');
```

I'm trying to get each div inside that given DIV and place it into an array, which works if I use:

```
var menuButtons = $('#myDivIDHere').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

However, if I use:

```
var menuButtons = masterContainer.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

I get this error in the console.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'parentContainer.getElementsByTagName('div', masterContainer)')

If I output $(masterContainer); to the console it returns the correct element, and this code is working perfectly:

```
var experimentOneMenuButton = $(masterContainer).children().last();
```

So I'm stumped, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `masterContainer`?

Comment: Try `$(masterContainer).find('div');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jQuery [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

```
var menuButtons = $('#myDivIDHere').find('div');
```

or

```
var menuButtons = $(masterContainer).find('div');
```

in your `experimentOne()` method

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) is a dom method, but `$('#myDivIDHere')` is a jQuery object where you don't have `getElementsByTagName`.

If you want to use `getElementsByTagName`, you need to use `$(masterContainer)[0].getElementsByTagName` where `$(masterContainer)[0]` gives you the dom reference.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the .getElementsByTagName is a method on the jQuery object.

You need to use

```
var menuButtons = $('#myDivIDHere').get(0).getElementsByTagName('div');
```

the .get(0) will return the DOM object, not the jQuery object

Comment: Sorry, get() will return an array of DOM objects, which I believe is what you are looking for.